# EF6, DbContext/POCO setting virtual nav property to attach new object: possible?

Tags: entity-framework-6

I am in the process of switching a very old EF6 edmx/ObjectContext implementation over to DbContext/POCO. I was able to generate the POCO model and all read operations seem to be working now.

My problem is that I have thousands of lines of code that do things like this:

```
var person = db.Persons.Single(x=> x.Id = 45);
var phone = new Phone { Person = person, Number = "123-456-7890"};
```

In the old edmx/ObjectContext world, when I set `Person = person`, the State of `phone` would be `Added`.

In the new DbContext/POCO world, this set has no effect at all, and the state remains `Detached`.

The new model code is using something like this to create the navigation property:

```
public virtual Person Person { get; set; }
```

Whereas the old edmx code was a getter setter, and the setter was doing this:

```
((IEntityWithRelationships)this).RelationshipManager
    .GetRelatedReference<Phone>("Model.fk_Person_Phone", "Person")
    .Value = value;
```

Is there any way to make the `virtual` nav property work similarly to the old method, and attach the new object to the database?

Comment: Looks like we're going to have to convert all the references. [This Microsoft article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/proxies) is the best explanation I found of how the virtual nav properties actually works.